# Shall we apply a limit for pagetoken, Because I am getting 400000 rows, due to this api's getting worker unresponsive error

Tags: transform, message, mulesoft

Getting the 400000 rows.
By using pagetoken we calling the database(bigquery table)
api's are getting worker unresponsve error
So Needs to apply limit to fetch rows count.

Applyied page token
still we are getting huge data.